# Video moves sideways when captured raw from camera and piped into ffplay

Tags: ffmpeg, avfoundation

I'm trying to capture video from the camera using `ffmpeg` (macOS 10.12) and pipe it for preview into `ffplay` using `rawvideo` and `-v copy` options:

```
ffmpeg -f avfoundation -pixel_format 0rgb -framerate 25 -video_size 1280x720 -i "0" -map 0:v -c copy -f rawvideo - | ffplay -f rawvideo -video_size 1280x720 -pixel_format 0rgb -i -
```

Video captures just fine, however, it constantly moves sideways (see screenshot attached). What might the issue here?

[image]

**UPDATE** Full `ffmpeg` log output:

```
$ ffmpeg -f avfoundation -pixel_format 0rgb -framerate 25 -video_size 1280x720 -i "0" -map 0:v -c copy -f rawvideo - | ffplay -f rawvideo -video_size 1280x720 -pixel_format 0rgb -i -
ffmpeg version 4.0.2ffplay version 4.0.2 Copyright © 2003-2018 the FFmpeg developers Copyright © 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers

  built with Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)
  built with Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.0.2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-gpl --enable-ffplay --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --enable-videotoolbox --disable-lzma
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.0.2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-gpl --enable-ffplay --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --enable-videotoolbox --disable-lzma
  libavutil      56. 14.100 / 56. 14.100
  libavutil      56. 14.100 / 56. 14.100
  libavcodec     58. 18.100 / 58. 18.100
  libavformat    58. 12.100 / 58. 12.100
  libavcodec     58. 18.100 / 58. 18.100
  libavdevice    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
  libavformat    58. 12.100 / 58. 12.100
  libavfilter     7. 16.100 /  7. 16.100
  libavdevice    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libavfilter     7. 16.100 /  7. 16.100
  libswscale      5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
  libswresample   3.  1.100 /  3.  1.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libpostproc    55.  1.100 / 55.  1.100
  libswscale      5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
  libswresample   3.  1.100 /  3.  1.100
  libpostproc    55.  1.100 / 55.  1.100
2018-09-20 09:33:28.013 ffmpeg[45781:16452887] Error loading /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/SeratoVirtualAudioPlugIn.plugin/Contents/MacOS/SeratoVirtualAudioPlugIn:  dlopen(/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/SeratoVirtualAudioPlugIn.plugin/Contents/MacOS/SeratoVirtualAudioPlugIn, 262): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/SeratoVirtualAudioPlugIn.plugin/Contents/MacOS/SeratoVirtualAudioPlugIn: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/SeratoVirtualAudioPlugIn.plugin/Contents/MacOS/SeratoVirtualAudioPlugIn: mach-o, but wrong architecture
2018-09-20 09:33:28.013 ffmpeg[45781:16452887] Cannot find function pointer New_SHP_PlugIn for factory 834FC054-C1CC-11D6-BD01-00039315CD46 in CFBundle/CFPlugIn 0x7fe63b506d00 </Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/SeratoVirtualAudioPlugIn.plugin> (bundle, not loaded)
2018-09-20 09:33:28.069 ffplay[45782:16452888] Error loading /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/SeratoVirtualAudioPlugIn.plugin/Contents/MacOS/SeratoVirtualAudioPlugIn:  dlopen(/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/SeratoVirtualAudioPlugIn.plugin/Contents/MacOS/SeratoVirtualAudioPlugIn, 262): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/SeratoVirtualAudioPlugIn.plugin/Contents/MacOS/SeratoVirtualAudioPlugIn: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/SeratoVirtualAudioPlugIn.plugin/Contents/MacOS/SeratoVirtualAudioPlugIn: mach-o, but wrong architecture
2018-09-20 09:33:28.069 ffplay[45782:16452888] Cannot find function pointer New_SHP_PlugIn for factory 834FC054-C1CC-11D6-BD01-00039315CD46 in CFBundle/CFPlugIn 0x7f93f3c13020 </Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/SeratoVirtualAudioPlugIn.plugin> (bundle, not loaded)
[avfoundation @ 0x7fe63c000000] Stream #0: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize
Input #0, avfoundation, from '0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 1054.178167, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo ([0]RGB / 0x42475200), 0rgb, 1280x720, 1000k tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
Output #0, rawvideo, to 'pipe:':   0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.12.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo ([0]RGB / 0x42475200), 0rgb, 1280x720, q=2-31, 1000k tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 ©
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Input #0, rawvideo, from 'pipe:':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 737280 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo ([0]RGB / 0x42475200), 0rgb, 1280x720, 737280 kb/s, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
frame=   16 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 size=   57600kB time=00:00:00.60 bitrate=786437.5kbits/s speed=1.frame=   29 fps= 28 q=-1.0 size=  104401kB time=00:00:01.12 bitrate=763617.4kbits/s speed=1.frame=   42 fps= 27 q=-1.0 size=  151201kB time=00:00:01.64 bitrate=755268.5kbits/s speed=1.frame=   55 fps= 26 q=-1.0 size=  198002kB time=00:00:02.16 bitrate=750939.5kbits/s speed=1.frame=   68 fps= 26 q=-1.0 size=  244802kB time=00:00:02.68 bitrate=748290.4kbits/s speed=1.av_interleaved_write_frame(): Broken pipe=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
Error writing trailer of pipe:: Broken pipe
frame=   69 fps= 26 q=-1.0 Lsize=  247650kB time=00:00:02.72 bitrate=745863.6kbits/s speed=1.01x    
video:248402kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
Exiting normally, received signal 2.
```

Comment: Share full log of the ffmpeg command.

Comment: @Gyan please see the update

Comment: Does the same issue occur when playing the video directly with ffplay: `ffplay -f avfoundation -pixel_format 0rgb -framerate 25 -video_size 1280x720 -i "0"`

Comment: good call! no it does not...

Comment: Then let ffmpeg transcode and check, remove `-c copy`

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but one frame was rendered and that's it -- no more. However, I saw this warning: `Frame rate very high for a muxer not efficiently supporting it. Please consider specifying a lower framerate, a different muxer or -vsync 2` and tried adding `-vsync 2` option and it worked! I, however, don't understand exactly what's the problem is and how `-vsync 2` helped to resolve it. Do you have an idea? Thanks!

Comment: avfoundation is reporting the framerate of the source as `1000k tbr` i.e. a million, and for constant frame rate muxers, ffmpeg will duplicate frames to get that rate if input rate is lacking. `-vsync vfr` or 2 disables that behaviour.

Comment: @Gyan thanks! do you want to move this to an answer? as it solves the problem for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does looks like the avfoundation device is padding the extra 32 bytes onto each packe, and thus leading to the progressive change in stride, which shows up as a gradual shift in horizontal alignment.

Transcoding the stream forces a decode, which gets rids of the padding.

The warning of `Frame rate very high for a muxer not efficiently supporting it` is not connected to this issue. The `avfoundation` device is registering a framerate of 1 million (!) which is an issue for constant frame rate muxers, since ffmpeg will seek to duplicate frames to meet that rate in the output. `-vsync vfr` sidesteps that problem.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like an issue with alignment/padding.  Since ffplay doesn't seem to have options for that, try different bigger video widths for ffplay instead of 1280 like 1282 or more.

Comment: Thanks, I played around with different settings for width and/or height but nothing helped. This made me try one thing though, I saved 1 frame of video to a file (using `-vframes 1`) and checked this file size `wc -c` in bytes and it shows `3686432` instead of `3686400` (which is 1280x720x4) -- which is exactly 8 pixels (32 bytes) more. So I believe, `ffmpeg` adds some header for each frame. Need to figure out how to skip it no...